# Stop a running Python script in Abaqus from a command line

Tags: python, command, abaqus

I am trying to stop a running Python script in Abaqus from the outside. I know that there is a button in the CAE GUI to stop a script, but what if I run the script with noGUI from a command line like this:

```
abaqus cae noGUI='script.py'
```

Is there a possibility to stop this script from running? Maybe I could cancel the Python-process in the background with some command?

Thanks for your help,
Fel

Answer (score 0):

You can quit any process by killing it from the command line. Here is an example with python where we kill all processes with python in the name.

`killall -9 python`